# how to enforce a database self join (or is there a better way)

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

I have an employees table in a database, and I want to link an employee to their manager:

### **Employee** Table

- employee_id
- first_name
- last_name
- manager_id

If the manager_id is just another row in the same table where the manager has it as their employee, what is the best way to enforce that if I delete an employee it verifies that this employee is not the manager of another employee?

Is there a better best practice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **self join** just like you join to other tables using  **PK** & **FK**.

I think you should design this with some things to consider. Examples:

- **Different Managers:** Tom is a Jr. Pgmr today, and Jerry is his Manager today. Tomorrow Tom may report to Sebastian.
- **Promotions:** Tom is a Jr. Pgmr today, and Jerry is his Manager today. Tomorrow Tom may become a manager himself and have people reporting to him.
- **Promotions 2:** Tom may go from Jr Pgmr to Sr Pgmr to Team Lead to Project Lead to Manager. Do you want to save this?
- **Reporting:** You may want to show hierarchy at a point in time (some user will come ask for this for a report sooner or later)

You may want to consider splitting up the data into separate entities - normalizing the data as follows (or even more as your needs may be)

- **Employees Table:** Basic employee info
- **Position Lookup Table:** List of all positions in the organization
- **Employee Position Table:** Track with start date and end date when a position change occurred for the employee.
- **Employee Position Hierarchy Table:** What Employee Position reports to another Employee Position (using a double join instead of a self join); with start and end timestamps

Comment: thanks for the response.  with all of your cases, as long as every employee has a manager, i should be able to generate a full heirarchy at any point in time

Comment: Then you presumably have more  columns than you are showing us to keep track of status changes with timestamps.

Comment: What about employees who report to multiple managers, temporary managers, or work in a matrix organization? What about different management roles?

Comment: true . . i have simplified it and i am not tracking changes over time.  simply updating with the latest info . .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a foreign key constraint (without cascading delete). If you try to delete a manager that still has other employees under him, the database will detect that automatically and the operation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreign key, here is a "usual" approach to this:

[image: employee_model_01]

Answer (score 0):

Use a many-to-many association to cover your bases, should your application (or organization) evolve.

```
Employee.Employee_id  <- EmployeeManager.Employee_id 
                         EmployeeManager.Manager_id -> Employee.Employee_id
                         Manager_role_type
                         etc.
```

Always use foreign key constraints.